# Not able to create home screen shortcut

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I am creating a home screen shortcut for my app using following code:

```
            HomeScreenShortCut.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            HomeScreenShortCut.putExtra("duplicate", false);
            //shortcutIntent is added with addIntent
            Intent addIntent = new Intent();
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, HomeScreenShortCut);
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Handbook Manual");
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                    Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"); 
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

This is working fine and shortcut is getting created. But, rather than hardcoding the name of shortcut, I want to give it from string file like this:

```
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, R.string.app_name);
```

But after making this change shortcut is not getting created which is really wierd. I need this as my app supports multiple languages and even the name of app is based on language. I am testing on Samsung Galaxy S3.

Please help..

Comment: have you tried using `getString(R.string.app_name)`? Remember that `R.string.app_name` is an integer, not a string.

Comment: Try this `youractivity.this.getString(R.string.app_name)`

Comment: @Merlevede .. You are correct. using getString solved the problem. I should have got that. It was simple :). Anyways you can move your comment to answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is!

Have you tried using `getString(R.string.app_name)`? Remember that `R.string.app_name` is an integer, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try to used this coding in the app

```
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
```

instead of this

```
  addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, R.string.app_name);
```

i hope this help u